# How to create common functionality for multiple type of users in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am working on larvel project. This project has two users

```
1) Admin
2) Customer
```

For Customer and Admin I have respective controllers

```
CustomerController.php for customer
AdminController.php for admin
```

Each and every module of customer's can also be manipulated from admin.
Like customer can be added from customer's panel as well as from admin panel and the record would be inserted into the user's table.

As I have mentioned that controllers are different for both. That's why for adding or editing details of users now I have to write two functions with 80% same code, one in AdminController.php file and other in CustomerConroller.php file.

I want this redundant code to be operated from single source.

What approach should I use to achieve it, should I use model files for CRUD operations ?

Comment: did you use admin or status column in your table? you can use this column and create middleware for use everwhere.

Comment: No admin records are being managed from admins table, we have multiple admins because.

Comment: You can create only one function and call it from any controller like: `app('App\Http\Controllers\AdminController')->yourFunctionName();` Using this, you don't need to write same code in it and call from that function!

Comment: And you can paste all same code in `AdminController` function and then call this from `CustomerController` and then execute other things after calling it! Hope you understand! If you still didn't get idea let me know I will post my answer with some code!

Comment: You can make a helper class like these way (i.e. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-laravel-helper--cms-28537).

Answer (score 0):

You can use roles and permission feature in laravel.
please go through the [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/user-authorization-in-laravel-54-with-spatie-laravel-permission)  for more information about how to implement roles and permission in laravel.

Comment: It's not about roles and permission actually, I only meant to say that what approach should I use to create common function that can be used for both admin as well as customer from technical aspects.

Comment: You can create common  method in your model files so you can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`Service` pattern](https://m.dotdev.co/design-pattern-service-layer-with-laravel-5-740ff0a7b65f), the idea is you abstract the logic to another layer (service layer), which can be used in multiple places, easier and better maintenance should you need to modify it in the future. You'd only need to modify one place instead of multiple places.

For example, if you want to create coupon in multiple places, a `CreateCouponService` can be injected into the controller and you can just call the service as the code below (taking from the article):

```
public function store(CreateCoupon $request)
{
  $this->createCouponService->make($request);

  return back()->with(['success' => 'Congratulations!']);
}
```

There's also the [`Repository` pattern](http://vegibit.com/laravel-repository-pattern/), to decouple the dependencies between models and controllers.

Things to take note is that all these are not mandatory and might be overkill should you only have a very straight forward CRUD application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use models

in your `AdminController` and `CustomerController` you can use static functions

```
 //your controller method
 public function store(Request $request){
   Yourmodel::save_request($request);
   return 'save';
 }

// your model class
class Yourmodel{
  public static function save_request($request){
   // do sometining
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write the main class with common functionalities and use inheritance for 
CustomerController
AdminController